# How is the __LINE__ and __FILE__ constants implemented in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

It seems the `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` constants are dynamically updated with the current file and line numbers under execution, I am wondering how is the behaviour implemented in Ruby?

I've greped the source code but there are too many noises for `__LINE__` and `__FILE__` appearance, I am wonder anyone could help me point to the source code and provide a clue to understand its behaviour.

Explanation in either `Rubinis` or `MRI` will be fine.

Comment: Maybe have a look at the source?

Comment: Why the downvote? Seems like a good question to me.

Comment: @CodyCaughlan: could you point to relevant file/line? I'm curious myself :)

Comment: @CodyCaughlan could you help point to the files:lines in the source code. I grep for the `__LINE__` but too much noises and hard to zero in on the exact code. If you could help, I will be quite thankful!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Both `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` get replaced by literals [directly in the parser](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_0_0_0/parse.y#L8411):

```
case keyword__FILE__:
    return NEW_STR(rb_external_str_new_with_enc(ruby_sourcefile, strlen(ruby_sourcefile),
                                                rb_filesystem_encoding()));
case keyword__LINE__:
    return NEW_LIT(INT2FIX(tokline));
```

In other words, they behave exactly as if you had typed in the resulting string or number yourself.

Note that for `__LINE__`, this [doesn't always behave how you'd expect](http://erniemiller.org/2012/09/10/ruby-tidbit-__line__-and-heredocs/).

Comment: @hammar Thanks for the source code. I am not familiar with the parser,  both the `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` are called from the static function `gettable_gen`. Does it mean **everytime** `__LINE__` is called from ruby, `NEW_STR()` is called to generate the dynamic value?

Comment: @steven.yang: No, parsing only happens once when your file is loaded. There is no "call" to `__LINE__` after that. It's all just constants from then on. It's like if before you ran your program, you gave your ruby file to a friend who went through it and manually replaced each occurrence of `__FILE__` with the file name and each occurrence  of `__LINE__` with the line number and then you loaded that file into ruby instead.

Comment: @hammar Then, why `__LINE__`, ** as a constant** is updated while the program is executed. This variable must not point to one fixed memory space. My first understanding is `NEW_LIT` is called every time for the resolution of `__LINE__`.

Comment: @steven.yang: I don't know where you got that idea from. It's not. When the file is loaded, if there is a `__LINE__` on line 2, it's replaced by a `2`. There is no variable. Nothing to update.

Comment: You mean for **every** appearance of `__LINE__` (be it on line 2, line 3 etc.) are replaced with the line numbers for that expression all at once?

Comment: @steven.yang: Yes. At parse time, when your file is loaded, before any part of your code even starts running. It's a purely syntactic thing.

Comment: @hammar Thanks. I finally understood it. Sorry for my lack of basic  knowledge about how a parser works.